# https disabled jekyll themes

Tags: http, https, jekyll, github-pages

I created my homepage with github pages and customize the domain to [**http://www.namespace-pt.com**](http://www.namespace-pt.com). As the following figure shows, everything turns out to be okay when I use **http** protocal.

[image]

However, when I tried to check `enforce https` option in github pages settings and visit [**https://www.namespace-pt.com**](https://www.namespace-pt.com), the jekyll theme cayman-blog is disabled and everything is in a mess.

Could anyone help me?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because [of mixed content](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https#resolving-problems-with-mixed-content):

> If you enable HTTPS for your GitHub Pages site but your site's HTML still references images, CSS, or JavaScript over HTTP, then your site is serving mixed content. Serving mixed content may make your site less secure and cause trouble loading assets.
>
> To remove your site's mixed content, make sure all your assets are served over HTTPS by changing `http://` to `https://` in your site's HTML.

In your case, [`lorepirri/cayman-blog/_layouts/default.html`](https://github.com/lorepirri/cayman-blog/blob/8a1b5a01bcbee0392a90ab5202de48bc574d4c60/_layouts/default.html#L51) does include:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/assets/css/style.css?v=' | \
                               append: site.github.build_revision | absolute_url }}">
```

If `absolute_url` generates an *`http://`* URL, that would be an issue when you enforce HTTPS.

---

The [OP namespace-Pt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13491606/namespace-pt) references in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68329044/https-disabled-jekyll-themes/68329281?noredirect=1#comment120761886_68329281) to [`jekyll/jekyll` issue 5590](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5590)

> While for assets with an `absolute_url` it may still be an `http://` call, we recommend using the `relative_url` for it anyways.

So the OP adds:

> I tried to change the `absolute_url` to `relative_url`, as all my assets are stored locally. It works.

Comment: Thank you VonC. I check out through chrome developer tools and I find it is indeed what happened. However, I still cannot find a way to get rid of it. Can I just change the href to `'/assets/css/style.css?v=' | append: site.github.build_revision`?

Comment: @namespace-Pt Do you have in your Jekyll options (like https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/) an URL starting with `http://`? (like `base_url`)

Comment: No, I tried to add `https://namespace-pt.com` to it and run locally by bundle, however it fails. I think it's because I can only use `127.0.0.1` as the baseurl locally. I now try to push it to github and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to change the `absolute_url` to `relative_url` accoding to [this issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5590) as all my assets are stored locally. It works.

Comment: @namespace-Pt Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.